# How to get average, max, min etc. from a group of object in ElasticSearch

Tags: statistics, elasticsearch

I'm using an `elasticsearch` db to store data for benchmarks.

I need to calculate and retrieve the average, max, min, etc. of a Group of values.

I have something like:

```
Index = "myindex"

Type = "mytype"
```

Each object has 3 fields:

```
"load_time", "execution_time", "log_time".
```

I then run the benchmark and db is populated with hundreds of records. Now, I would retrieve the average, the max and the min value for each field.

What query should I run?
I tried with statistical facet but I Always get a "unreognized token exception"...

Answer (score 3):

You should use the statistical facet ([doc](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-facets-statistical-facet.html))

The query should be something like:

```
{
    "query" : {
        "match_all" : {}
    },
    "facets" : {
        "statload_time" : {
            "statistical" : {
                "field" : "load_time"
            }
        },
        "statexec_time" : {
            "statistical" : {
                "field" : "execution_time"
            }
        },
        "statlog_time" : {
            "statistical" : {
                "field" : "log_time"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As the doc says:

> The statistical data include count, total, sum of squares, mean
>   (average), minimum, maximum, variance, and standard deviation

After indexing a couple of documents, the response of the query is:

```
{
  "took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "facets" : {
    "statload_time" : {
      "_type" : "statistical",
      "count" : 2,
      "total" : 7.0,
      "min" : 2.0,
      "max" : 5.0,
      "mean" : 3.5,
      "sum_of_squares" : 29.0,
      "variance" : 2.25,
      "std_deviation" : 1.5
    },
    "statexec_time" : {
      "_type" : "statistical",
      "count" : 2,
      "total" : 12.0,
      "min" : 5.0,
      "max" : 7.0,
      "mean" : 6.0,
      "sum_of_squares" : 74.0,
      "variance" : 1.0,
      "std_deviation" : 1.0
    },
    "statlog_time" : {
      "_type" : "statistical",
      "count" : 2,
      "total" : 16.0,
      "min" : 7.0,
      "max" : 9.0,
      "mean" : 8.0,
      "sum_of_squares" : 130.0,
      "variance" : 1.0,
      "std_deviation" : 1.0
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying this, but I get the error "unreognized token exception", saying that:

{"error":"MapperParsingException[failed to parse]; nested: JsonParseException[Unrecognized token 'load_time': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')

Comment: @CarmineGiangregorio can you post your mapping?